# Dealing with a POST Ajax in rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters, controller

Hi so I have this **POST** request

```
        .click(function() {

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "../quotes/create",
                data: {
                    name : "John ",
                    email: "john@john.com",
                    json: "data",
                    uid: "uid",
                 },
                 dataType:'text',
                 success: function(data,status,xhr){
                    console.log(status);
                   alert("SUCCESS!");
                 },
                 error: function(xhr,status,error){
                   console.log(status,error);
                   alert("ERROR!");
                 }

            });

        })
```

in my **controller** I have the following:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render text: "Your data was sucessfully loaded. Thanks"}
  end
end
```

On click I get the "SUCCESS!"message. Im just confused how to take this forward.

I basically want to store this data in a way like this

```
@quote = Quote.create(quote_params)

if @quote.save
  flash[:success] = "Quote Created :)"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'new'
end

private

def quote_params
  params.require(:quotes).permit(:uid, :name, :email, :json)
end
```

**Any ideas on how to get the params data here in the controller and then get the page to redirect to the root_url after "SUCCESS!" ?**

Comment: If you want to `redirect` to another page, you do not need do `ajax` at all.

Comment: Yup I know I can do that in the controller. I need to get the PARAMS thats this POST sends.

Comment: for example you can override quote_params method to contain params.permit(:name, :email, :json, :uid)

Comment: @MikeHolford I think @blelump is saying that if you are redirecting the user after the `POST` request, what's the point of using `AJAX`? You typically want to use `AJAX` when you _don't_ want a redirect. That being said, @D.K.'s comment is correct, just write your `quote_params` method to accept the params from your `POST` request and it should work.

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying @mmichael. I have edited my question to show my quote_params. Do i need to put the `@quotes= Quote.create` etc.. within the `respond_to do |format|` ?

Comment: Seeings as I don't need Ajax here can I just remove the `$.ajax` ? Sorry im not very hot on javascript so bit of a mind muddle dealing with it

Comment: Well, first you probably want to use `new` instead of `create` so you'd write `@quote = Quote.new(quote_params)` and your `quote_params` method should be `params.require(:quote).permit(:uid, :name, :email, :json)`. However, and most importantly, if this is a Rails app why not use a Rails form instead of JS? Is a user submitting a form in the view that creates the quote?

Comment: Thanks @mmichael Ill give it a whirl. The form is a complex javascript form and I have the job in saving their post request in our database with the controller. If it was a rails form it would be much easier :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get `param is missing or the value is empty: quote` in the dev console on chrome @mmichael

Comment: With your code above, you'll want to either remove the `require(:quote)` from your `quote_params` method or modify your `AJAX` code to wrap the params in the `quote` key: `data: {quote: {                    name : "John ", email: "john@john.com", json: "data", uid: "uid"}}`